# Why result order changed after add group by to a query sentence?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

DB: MySQL 5.6

`users` table:

```
| id | name |
| -- | ---- |
| 1  | A    |
| 2  | B    |
```

`user_likes` table:

```
| id | user_id | star | created_at          |
| -- | ------- | ---- | ------------------- |
| 1  | 1       | 2    | 2018-09-12 00:00:00 |
| 2  | 2       | 3    | 2018-09-12 00:00:00 |
```

Query 1

```
select u.name, ul.user_id
from users u, user_likes ul
where u.id = ul.user_id
order by ul.star desc, ul.created_at desc;
```

Query 2

```
select u.name, ul.user_id
from users u, user_likes ul
where u.id = ul.user_id
group by ul.user_id
order by ul.star desc, ul.created_at desc;
```

Why result order changed after add `group by ul.user_id` in this case?

So want to get unique user_id record from `user_likes`, how to do?

Comment: If you're using the same `ORDER BY` clause in two queries, and both have the same result sets, then the order has to be the same AFAIK.  If you want unique records, then, in the second query, either do `GROUP BY u.name, ul.user_id` or do `SELECT DISTINCT u.name, ul.user_id`, with no `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Isnt Query 2 giving you an error because you have a non-aggregated column?

Comment: @VishnuKunchur - no, MySql will, for some terrible reason, allow you to not use group by.  It instead does some basically random grouping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you aren't using any aggregation column and your fields aren't the one on `GROUP BY` or `ORDER BY` you are getting random rows.

In your first query you `order by ul.star desc, ul.created_at desc` if multiple rows have same star and same created_at the result can give your random order for those row.

On your second query you first `group by user.id`  but you don't have any aggregations. there for the field on your select can get any row belong to that group again any random result.

When I said random is more like underterministic, because isnt like a different result each time. Usually depend how the data was stored or if an index was used.

Comment: Thank you. By the way, is there a way do `order by` first, then unique `users.name`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. But if is a different problem create a new question. And include sample data and desire output

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT users.name , user_likes.user_id 
FROM user 
JOIN user_likes 
  ON user.id = user_likes.user_id  
 GROUP BY user.id  
order by user_likes.star desc, user_likes.created_at desc;
```

Best Way Result

Comment: I found it's the same as `Query 2`.